# get the div object that holds a jquery widget from inside the widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, widget, jquery-widgets

I have the following code:

```
<div id="widHolder"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('#widHolder').widgetName({
        optionOne: false,
        optionTwo: 1,
        onComplete: function (holder) { 
            // ... do something here with the 'widHolder' object such as $(holder).addClass(x,y) 
        }
    });
</script>
```

Within the widget itself, the onComplete method will be called immediately after the full initialization of the widget.  I want the code within the widget to reference the object that the widget is linked to (in this case, the div with the id 'widHolder').

My goal is to be able to quickly and easily reference the holding object by creating the oncomplete function as listed above.  The code in the widget itself will just be to call the onComplete function passing the holder (which I need to get) as a parameter.

Here is the code sample of the jQuery UI Widget plugin

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget("ui.widgetName", {
        options: {
            // ... other options that can be set
            onComplete: undefined
        },

        // called on the initialization of the widget
        _init: function () {
            // do initialization functions...

            if(this.options.onComplete)
                this.options.onComplete( I_WANT_TO_SEND_THE_DOM_ELEMENT_HERE );
        },
    }
})
```

Comment: Can we have a link to the page you are using this on, or see more code. Despite how long the code may be, it's harder to interpret what's going on than it would be to understand the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The jQuery UI Widget Factory makes the element available via:

`this.element` from with the plugin.

For more information, please take a look here: http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory

Does that better answer your question?

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget("ui.widgetName", {
        options: {
            // ... other options that can be set
            onComplete: undefined
        },

        // called on the initialization of the widget
        _init: function () {
            // do initialization functions...

            if(this.options.onComplete)
                this.options.onComplete( this.element );
        },
    }
})
```

Side note -  if you create another closure inside your plugin, you will need to save a reference to `this`.  For instance:

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget("ui.widgetName", {
        options: {
            // ... other options that can be set
            onComplete: undefined
        },

        // called on the initialization of the widget
        _init: function () {
            // do initialization functions...
            var self = this;
            $.each(an_array_or_something_obj, function(){
                //here this will refer to the current element of the an_array_or_something_obj
                //self will refer to the jQuery UI widget
            });
            if(this.options.onComplete)
                this.options.onComplete( this.element );
        },
    }
})
```

Comment: It's my understanding that if I use "this" within the widget then I am referring to the widget itself.  I've used this many, many times throughout the widget, but that's not what i'm trying to do here.  Here, I don't want to return the widget itself, but rather the container that the widget is linked to.  I'm sure that i could use something like, "this.container" but I don't know what that syntax is.

Comment: To answer your question - this is a jQuery UI plugin.  I'd rather not post the full plugin code as it is quite extensive and this is just a small update to the full plugin.

Comment: @Adam - jQuery UI handles some basic plumbing for you, such as setting a property `element` to reference the DOM element that the widget was called on.  I added it to your example and edited my answer above.

Comment: Hey - thanks... going through the code last night I found this as well.  "this.element" is just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.offsetParent` if, as in your example, the holder is the direct parent of the widget.

Comment: I tried this.offsetParent and $(this).offsetParent but neither worked.  I put these in the spot above that says I_WANT_TO_SEND_THE_DOM_ELEMENT_HERE.  I've updated the question to include a sample of the plugin code.  Perhaps I'm doing something wrong - let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: @Adam, Sorry, the scope of `this` always eludes me in javascript. Try `console.log(this)` to see what it's referring to.

Comment: @Walkerneo - this always refers to the closure.  So, in Adam's case, the jQuery UI Widget.  In a normal jQuery plugin, this, in the `init` method will refer to the jQuery object that the plugin was called on.

Comment: @Jonathan, Actually, `this` is referring to the object being passed as the second argument. Unless that's what you meant, though I can't tell.

Comment: @Walkerneo The second argument to `$.widget();`?  That is correct.  The first argument is the namespace of the widget, the second is the widget itself.  We are talking about the same object.